# how many processes can be there in behavioural of vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

i want to slow down clk...and take input

```
entity q1 is
    Port ( clk: in std_logic;
              a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           b0,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           y0,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
end q1;

architecture Behavioral of q1 is
signal counter : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)='0000000000';
signal clk_en: std_logic='0';
process(clk)
begin
     if (clk'event and clk='1') then
            counter <= counter +1;
            if (counter = 0) then
                clk_en <= '1';
            else clk_en='0' 
            end if ;
      end if;
end process;



end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Your question title and body do not match at all, and you have not presented an actual problem here. Also, take the time to format your code so that others have a chance of being able to read it.

Comment: The answer is : how many do you need?

Answer (score 0):

***an elaborated VHDL design executes proccesses***
IEEE Std 1076-2008:
11. Concurrent statements, 11.1 General, para 1:

> ...Concurrent statements are used to define interconnected blocks and processes that jointly describe the overall behavior or structure of a design. ...

And

14. Elaboration and execution 14.1 General:

> The process by which a declaration achieves its effect is called the elaboration of the declaration. After its elaboration, a declaration is said to be elaborated. Prior to the completion of its elaboration (including before the elaboration), the declaration is not yet elaborated.
>
> Elaboration is also defined for design hierarchies, declarative parts, statement parts (containing concurrent statements), and concurrent statements. Elaboration of such constructs is necessary in order ultimately to elaborate declarative items that are declared within those constructs.
>
> In order to execute a model, the design hierarchy defining the model shall first be elaborated. Initialization of nets (see 14.7.3.4) in the model then occurs. Finally, simulation of the model proceeds. Simulation consists of the repetitive execution of the simulation cycle, during which processes are executed and nets updated.

14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy, para 1:

> The elaboration of a design hierarchy creates a collection of processes interconnected by nets; this collection of processes and nets can then be executed to simulate the behavior of the design.

Every concurrent statement is elaborated as a process (process statements, concurrent procedure calls, concurrent assertion statements, concurrent signal assignments) or hierarchy of blocks and processes (generate statements, component instantiations and  block statements).

A process is not a routine, it isn't called. Rather it is *suspended* and resumed. It will wrap from the last statement to the first (goto or jump, not call).

How many processes can be held in a model isn't a matter of whether it is structural or behavioral - all VHDL models are behavioral, the distinction between the two is style not execution.

Along with a resumption address process resumption is controlled by sensitivity to events or simulation time. When a process suspends is controlled by the algorithm it implements.

***simulation***
14.7 Execution of a model
14.7.1 General, para 1:

> The elaboration of a design hierarchy produces a *model* that can be executed in order to simulate the design represented by the model. Simulation involves the execution of user-defined processes that interact with each other and with the environment. ...

Execution of a processes statements can occur concurrently with any other process in a model.  There is no guaranteed execution order and if they aren't concurrently executed the simulation cycle treats them as if they were.

No signal assignment occurs when any process is executing. When all processes have suspended any projected output waveform scheduled signal assignments are evaluated and the next time at which a signal update is scheduled is determined. Simulation time is advanced to that time.  A signal assignment scheduled to occur after 0 simulation time units occurs in the next delta cycle. When there are no further updates scheduled simulation time is advanced to the maximum time value and simulation ends.

***how many processes***
How many processes is implementation limitation, based more on CPU architecture (address space, size of address pointers). How many processes there can be is dependent on the total number of addressable things, model code and their size versus the size of pointers and the amount of executable code needed to support the simulation - the host operating system routines in the simulation model's memory space. The host's ability to deal with virtual memory.

Address space is commonly associated with a CPU's word size. It's implementation dependent and not a VHDL language definition limitation.

The consequence of implementation limitations affects portability.

**portability**
Annex D,
(informative),
Potentially nonportable constructs, paras 1:

> This annex lists those VHDL constructs whose use may result in nonportable descriptions.
> A description is considered portable if it
>
> a) Compiles, elaborates, initializes, and simulates to termination of the simulation cycle on all conformant implementations, and
>
> b) The time-variant state of all signals and variables in the description are the same at all times during the simulation,
>
> under the condition that the same stimuli are applied at the same times to the description. The stimuli applied to a model include the values supplied to generics and ports at the root of the design hierarchy of the model, if any.

VHDL design specifications can be non-portable between implementations based on implementation limitations. Annex D enumerates non portable constructs that defined in the language definition, which does not include implementation limitations.